# Primefaces layout can't scroll the whole page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it true we can't scroll the whole page that implement primefaces fullpage layout ? Is the layout must take only the size of the page ? i can't make this happen, if i do overflow : hidden so it hides my layoutnuit content and doesn't scroll the page !

Answer (score 1):

yes you can't scroll the whole page that implement primefaces fullpage layout.
it is not possible  it will either cause scrollbars  or it will be partially hidden.
try not to use layout if you want to scroll the whole page.

Comment: Thanks for the info nordine, i think i ll just move to layout otherwise !